# ¿Cómo convertir datos binarios a texto C++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa en `C++` que me permita guardar información en archivos de texto como por ejemplo un archivo con nombres en un archivo binario, y que me permita leerlo después y obtener el texto originar, hasta ahora puedo guardar el archivo, pero al leerlo no se como obtener el texto original, es decir, solo obtengo datos binarios, y pues soy muy nuevo usando `C++`.

Este es el código que me permite escribir un archivo binario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    //Suponiendo que ya tenemos el dato a escribir y el tamaño del bloque
    std::fstream archivo_a_escribir;
    archivo_a_escribir.open("archivo.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    archivo_a_escribir.write(datos, tamaño);

    //Ahora cierro el archivo
    archivo_a_escribir.close();
}
```

Y tengo este código que leer el archivo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    std::fstream archivo_a_leer;
    //Leemos el archivo
    archivo_a_leer.open("archivo.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    archivo_a_leer.seekg(0, archivo_a_leer.end);
    int tamaño = archivo_a_leer.tellg();
    archivo_a_leer.seekg(0, archivo_a_leer.beg);

    //Para almacenar los datos
    char * datos = new char[tamaño];

    //Leemos el archivo
    archivo_a_leer.read(datos, tamaño);

    //Cerramos el archivo
    archivo_a_leer.close();

    //En esta parte tendría que obtener o convertir los datos en el texto original.

    //Una vez que hemos terminado de trabajar con los datos, liberamos memoria
    delete[] datos;
}
```

Lo que necesito hacer es obtener el texto original que esta almacenado en la variable `datos`, si pudieran ayudarme seria genial, sinceramente ya me cansé de buscar en `google`.

Comment: ¿Qué es `datos` en `archivo_a_escribir.write(datos, tamaño);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que escribieras una `std::string`

```
std::string cadena{ "Cualquier cosa que se te ocurra" };

...

archivo_a_escribir.write(cadena.c_str( ), cadena.size( ) );
```

Para *cargar* los datos en una `std::string( )`, puedes usar una de las variantes de la función miembro `assign( )`:

```
char * datos = new char[tamaño];
std::string cadena{ };

...

// Leemos el archivo
archivo_a_leer.read( datos, tamaño );

...

// Cargamos los datos en una std::string.
cadena.assign( datos, tamaño );
```

También podrías hacerlo directamente en el constructor de `std::string`:

```
char * datos = new char[tamaño];

...

// Leemos el archivo
archivo_a_leer.read( datos, tamaño );

...

// Creamos la cadena, enviando los datos directamente al constructor.
std::string cadena{ datos, tamaño };
```

#### Nota

Lo de `datos binarios a texto` indica un *leve* confusión por tu parte. Desde el punto de vista del equipo, **todo** son datos binarios; todo son números. Otra cosa es **la interpretación** de esos datos que **nosotros** o **nuestro programa** hagamos. Te sugiero, por ejemplo, echarle una ojeada a la [entrada ASCII de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).